# How do I get a matrix where I translate then rotate then translate then rotate a second time?

Tags: android, math, matrix

In an Android app I want to draw a running leg. To output the top part of the leg I do something like:

```
// legCX,legCY is the location on screen about which the leg rotates.
Matrix m = new Matrix();
m.postTranslate(-legCX,-legCY);
m.postRotate(legRot);
m.postTranslate(legCX,legCY);
```

I then set the matrix to the canvas and draw the leg.

How do I draw the second part of the leg below the knee? It rotates at a different rate than the leg above it and has a center point which moves with the leg above it. I tried the following, but it turns out that the end result is rotation around some single point which doesn't follow the leg above.

```
Matrix m = new Matrix();
m.postTranslate(-legCX,-legCY);
m.postRotate(legRot);
m.postTranslate(0,-legLength);
m.postRotate(footRot);
m.postTranslate(0,legLength);
m.postTranslate(legCX,legCY);
```

I suspect that it's probably necessary to do the two rotations in two different Matrix objects and then combine them somehow, but I can't figure out how exactly to do that.

EDIT:
This type of matrix seems to be called a "transformation matrix". Combining multiple operations is called composition of transformations. However, none of the pages on this topic mention how to do a series of translations and rotations.

Surely, if you can use a matrix to do rotation about one point, it must be possible to do multiple matrix operations somehow to allow rotation about one point and then an additional rotation around a different point.

I've tried looking at pages on skeletal animation, but I can't make head nor tail of what they're talking about.

Comment: Seems you forgot to undo `legRot`. Except for your innermost rotation, all other operations should be perfectly balanced. You can achieve this by adding the reverse rotation at the appropriate position, or by combining the first three operations into a single matrix and applying that matrix first and its inverse afterwards. If this solves your problem, I'll turn this comment into an answer.

Comment: this didn't work. I wish I could find a tutorial on how to do this, but either it's not possible or I'm searching for the wrong thing.

Answer (score 6):

If I understand you problem correctly, you have a relative rotation case. You can try to search for double pendulum, see fig.

[image: double pendulum]

Using rotation matrix the new coordinates of point `p1` rotated around point `p0` can be found like

[image]

The new coordinates of point `p2` rotated around point `p1` will be

[image]

Finally, the new coordinates of point `p2` rotated around point `p0` will be

[image]

Order of matrices multiplication matters as well the sign of the angles.

Comment: I figure out the answer over on gamedev. I'm not really sure if the final solution I got there corresponds to the actual math you're doing here. It doesn't look like it, but I am not entirely sure what the Matrix object might be doing.

http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/50171/what-matrix-operations-do-i-perform-to-translate-then-rotate-then-translate-then

Answer (score 2):

I'm afraid this is going to be language-agnostic - I'm actually doing something similar at the moment in Android, but I'm both learning android and matrix math!  You seem to know how to use matrices in Android so I'm guessing this won't be a problem.

So - let's say we've got two meshes (where a mesh is the thing that you can draw independently to the screen): `UpperLeg` and `LowerLeg`.

- For `UpperLeg` you're going to have the point where the mesh rotates (`RotationPoint`)(in the real world I guess this would be the hip) and you're going to have the point where the `LowerLeg` attaches to it (`AttachmentPoint`)(in the real world I guess this would be the knee).
- For `LowerLeg` you're going to have the point where the mesh rotates (`RotationPoint`)(in the real world I guess this would be the knee).

`UpperLeg.AttachmentPoint` = `LowerLeg.RotationPoint` (that way your leg won't fall off).

Let's now imagine that you've got two amounts of rotation (one for `UpperLeg` and one for `LowerLeg`): `UpperLeg.Rotation` and `LowerLeg.Rotation`.

(One the subject of rotation - if you haven't heard of *Quaternions*, you should look - it amazes me that some guy from 1846 came up with these - they basically encapsulate the concept of rotation, can be turned into rotation matrices, can be combined (by multiplication) and don't suffer from Gimbal-lock).

First up you you rotate `UpperLeg` by:

1. Moving the `UpperLeg` mesh so that `UpperLeg.RotationPoint` is the origin
2. Rotating by `UpperLeg.Rotation`
3. Moving the `UpperLeg` mesh so that it is where it needs to be in the real world.
   I see that you're doing this.

So for the `LowerLeg` it'd be:

1. Moving the `LowerLeg` mesh so that `LowerLeg.RotationPoint` is the origin
2. Rotating by (`UpperLeg.Rotation` combined with `LowerLeg.Rotation`)
3. Moving the `LowerLeg` mesh by the same amount that the `UpperLeg` mesh was moved by in step 3
4. Moving the `LowerLeg` mesh by the Vector which is (the Vector from `UpperLeg.RotationPoint` to `UpperLeg.AttachmentPoint`) rotated by `UpperLeg.Rotation`.

The above steps can be combined and optimized.

Essentially I'm saying:
Rotate `LowerLeg` as it needs to be rotated, then shove it where it needs to go - where it needs to go will be determined by where `UpperLeg` went, plus how you get to where `LowerLeg` is attached to `UpperLeg`.

This is my first post here so, if I've broken any cardinal rules, please let me know what they are.